# Change name of folder when cloning from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When I clone something from Github, it creates a folder with the same name as the app on my computer. Is there a way to change the name?

For example, doing this clone creates a long "sign-in-with-twitter" folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter.git
```

I know I can rename the folder after, but I'm wondering if there's a way to rename it as it comes in by adding an option at the end of the statement. For example,

```
git clone https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter.git as 'signin'
```

the problem is that I'm cloning some apps multiple times in order to tweak some of the settings to get it to work, and if there's a problem, I delete the folder. But, I'm worried that some of the gems remain installed even though I've deleted the folder.

Comment: What did you mean by 'gems'?

Comment: @Milan probably ruby gems: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/libraries/

Answer (score 1373, accepted):

You can do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter.git signin

# or

git clone git@github.com:sferik/sign-in-with-twitter.git signin
```

[refer to the manual here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

Comment: If you want to avoid an additional folder layer you can replace `signin` with `.`

Comment: @Marged that should be its own answer by freng. Hope the Homer doing good by the way.

Comment: I tried the RTFM approach and failed (hence why I'm here), but if you run `git clone --help` it will give you something like this:  `git clone [--very-many-options...] <repository> [<directory>]`, so we see that `git clone repo_url my_directory` should work, as the above answer correctly shows.

Comment: @Marged, u should add your comment as one of the answer

Comment: @Marged what did you mean by *"If you want to avoid an additional folder layer... ?"*

Comment: @Milan Usually all files go into a folder with the name of the repo. You can leave this folder out and store the files in the current folder

Comment: @Marged Oh, now, I got it. So, basically, it will download the contents of the repo in the current directory without creating a new directory (having the same name as the name of the repo). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 82):

```
git clone <Repo> <DestinationDirectory>
```

Clone the repository located at Repo into the folder called DestinationDirectory on the local machine.

Answer (score 19):

In case you want to clone a specific branch only, then,

```
git clone -b <branch-name> <repo-url> <destination-folder-name>
```

for example,

```
git clone -b dev https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter.git signin
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is one more answer from @Marged in comments

1. Create a folder with the name you want
2. Run the command below from the folder you created

   ```
   git clone <path to your online repo> .
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Arrived here because my source repo had `%20` in it which was creating local folders with `%20` in them when using simplistic `git clone <url>`.

Easy solution:

`git clone https://teamname.visualstudio.com/Project%20Name/_git/Repo%20Name "Repo Name"`